# Help on app directories?

Tags: application-development

I am developing a program using glade + gtk through quickly, ubuntu 12.04. If a want to include a file .xml, where I have to create this file? Is there any default folder for that?

at the end when I deploy the app, do I have to put any extra setting anywhere?

its a bit confusing, I have java background, and in java you include everything on the root folder of the app and the code can read the files, but not sure in here.

Answer (score 1):

Global settings and data : /opt/appname

User specfic data: /home/userme/appname

configuarations : ~./config/appname

Temporary files : /tmp

Comment: I am not a developer yet . Feel free to edit if any thing wrong in it

Comment: that is a common setting for a application when you already have this application installed, but when you are developing stage, how do I configure this.

Comment: @bas-brain `quickly ubuntusubmit`